# @KafkaListener skipping messages when using Acknowledgment.nack() after RecordInterceptor changed consumer record

Tags: spring-kafka

Let's assume the following [RecordInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/RecordInterceptor.html) to simply return a copy of the received consumer record.

```kotlin
class CustomRecordInterceptor : RecordInterceptor<Any, Any> {

  override fun intercept(record: ConsumerRecord<Any, Any>): ConsumerRecord<Any, Any>? {
    return with(record) {
      ConsumerRecord(
          topic(),
          partition(),
          offset(),
          timestamp(),
          timestampType(),
          checksum(),
          serializedKeySize(),
          serializedValueSize(),
          key(),
          value(),
          headers(),
          leaderEpoch())
    }
  }
}
```

With such an interceptor in place, we experience lost records with the following Kafka listener.

Note: `record` is the result returned by the interceptor.

```kotlin
@KafkaListener(topics = ["topic"])
fun listenToEvents(
    record: ConsumerRecord<SpecificRecordBase, SpecificRecordBase?>,
    ack: Acknowledgment
) {
  if (shouldNegativelyAcknowledge()) {
    ack.nack(2_000L)
    return
  }
  processRecord(record)
  ack.acknowledge()
}
```

Whenever `shouldNegativelyAcknowledge()` is true, we would expect that record to be reprocessed by the listener after > 2 seconds. We are using `ackMode = MANUAL`.

What we see however is that after a while the skipped record was not reprocessed by the listener: `processRecord` was never invoked for that record. After a while, the consumer group has a lag of 0.

While debugging, we found this code block in `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer#handleNack`:

```kotlin
if (next.equals(record) || list.size() > 0) {
  list.add(next);
}
```

- `next` is the record **after** the interceptor treatment (so it's the copy of the original record)
- `record` is the record **before** the interceptor treatment

Note that `next` and `record` can never be equal because `ConsumerRecord` does not override `equals`.

Could this be the cause for unexpectedly skipped records, maybe a bug even?

Or is it a misuse of the record interceptor to return a different ConsumerRecord object, not equal to the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and it does explain why the remaining records are not sent to the listener - please open an issue on GitHub

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues

Comment: The equality test will have to be the topic/partition/offset so the interceptor must always reflect those in any mutated record.

Comment: I opened it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2208

Comment: well, so I guess this one can be closed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2209

Comment: Sorry about that - the fix was simple so I went ahead. Thanks for finding/reporting this.

Comment: No worries, we very much appreciate it being fixed so quickly.